# Is there a way to manage admin panel edit permissions by model property in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions, django-extensions

So, I want to be able to control write permissions for a model in Django admin panel using model property value.

Here's an example: we have a model called `Organization` with property `is_production`, which is boolean. Also, we have two roles: `Developers` and `Customer Support`. I want users from `Developers` group to be able to edit Organizations with `is_production = False`, and users from `Customer Support` to be able to edit ones with `is_production = True`. Is there a no-code / low-code way to do it, like an extension / Django battery?

Thanks for your time!